# Cannot get value from generated by PHP URL Rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp, wamp

I have an issue when getting value from URL. I am using Wamp server 2.4 version and URL rewrite module is active.

I have following links ;

> http://www.demosite.com/site/newspage/10

I try to get value from linked page using **$_GET** method like that ;

```
<?php

if (  isset ( $_GET['id'] ) ) echo 'id: '.$_GET['id'].'<br>';

?>
```

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^newspage/(\w+)/(\d+)/\w+/? newspage.php?type=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
> RewriteRule ^newspage/(\d+)/\w+/? newspage.php?id=$1 [NC,L] 
> RewriteRule ^newspage/? newspage.php [NC,L]
> ```

i'm getting blank page !!! cannot get ID value..

But this code is working XAMMP server without issue. I can get value using XAMMP. But cannot get valu using Wamp server !

What is wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it works using XAMMP and doesn't work using WAMP would suggest configuration differences between the two packages.

Check for differences between the .htaccess file again and ensure that the .htaccess file in your XAMMP setup is the exact same as that of your WAMP setup. Following that, check for differences between the php.ini files.